# Eidei Nisuin at weddings?

Tags: marriage, edim-witnesses, kiddushin-eirusin

At a wedding, we designate both *eidei kiddushin* (witnesses for the kiddushin) and *eidei ketubah* (witnesses for the ketubah).

However, I haven't really seen the practice of designating *eidei nisuin* at a wedding except for yichud.

Recall the yichud room is only **one** opinion of what nisuin is; why don't we designate witnesses for the other opinions? (ie entering the chuppah, covering the kallah's face etc-- see [this answer](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/98286/18474))

Are *eidei nisuin*  required at a wedding?
If so, why aren't they designated/ set aside for all the different options of *nisuin* like they are for *kiddushin* and *ketubah*?

Comment: IMSMC we really only view the yichud as the actual nisuin, and the other customs are more of a chumra.

Comment: "*A possible practice outcome of viewing the badeken as the chuppa is that according to those opinions that require witnesses for the chuppa, the eidim should witness the badeken as well. Some Acharonim (see Teshuvot Ve-Hanhagot, EH 4:286:7, and Shevivei Eish, Hilkhot Chuppa Ve-Sheva Berakhot 1) mention this stringency and insist that the eidim view the badeken. However, it is generally accepted that be-di’avad, we do not view the badeken as a component of the marriage ceremony.*" -- https://www.etzion.org.il/en/introduction-hilkhot-ishut-year-2

Comment: @Loewian thanks! want to write as an answer?

Comment: I've seen people designate witnesses for badekin

Comment: http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=14552&st=&pgnum=28

Answer (score 5):

The simple answer is that the *eidei kiddushin* witness the *chupa*, *bideken* and *yichud*, which between them constitute *nissuin* too.

However, there is very convincing argument that *nissuin* does not require *eidim lkiyum*. Although by all *chaluyos* of *dovor sh'berva* we need *eidim lkiyum* (like *gerushin* and *kiddushin*, and others), there are two reasons why *nissuin* is different:

1) The Gemara in Kiddushin 65a writes that using the concept of *hoda'as baal din k'meah eidim dami*, one can circumvent the requirement for *eidim*, and the Kiddushin would theoretically be valid without *eidim*. (It is beyond the scope of this answer to explain how the two concept are interlinked). The reason the Gemara gives why this doesn't work is because when it is *chav l'acheirim* - detrimental to others - the concept of *hoda'as baal din* does not apply. Kiddushin is considered *chav l'acheirim* [either because the marriage causes the woman to become forbidden to all others, or because it causes him/her to become forbidden to each other's realtives - see Rashi & Rashba Kiddushin 65). Nissuin, however, is not *chav l'acheirim*, because both the relatives and the rest of the world are all already forbidden with the *Kiddushin*.

2) According to some (notably, R' Chaim Solovetzik), the requirement for *eidi kiyum* is only by a '*chalos ha'adam*' (in Achronistic parlance), not by a '*chalos hatorah*'. Nissuin is considered a *chalos hatorah*, and therefore does not require *eidim lkiyum*.

Therefore, some Poskim (e.g. [Or Someach](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=14552&st=&pgnum=28), linked by @JoelK)  do not require *eidim* by Nissuin.

Nevertheless, the Avnei Miluim (37:18) and HaMakneh (EH §50) rule that it is required. The simple reading of the Tosfos Ri Hazaken in Kiddushin 10a is that Nissuin does require *eidim*.

Comment: +1, but maybe you’d consider translating more of the Hebrew phrases here for people who aren’t familiar with them?